# ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 1523: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'admin_menu.PRIMARY

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `admin_menu` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `order` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `title` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `icon` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `uri` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `permission` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

### --
-- Dumping data for table `admin_menu`

```
INSERT INTO `admin_menu` (`id`, `parent_id`, `order`, `title`, `icon`, `uri`, `permission`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
(1, 0, 1, 'Dashboard', 'fa-bar-chart', '/', NULL, NULL, NULL),
(2, 0, 2, 'Admin', 'fa-tasks', '', NULL, NULL, NULL),
(3, 2, 3, 'Users', 'fa-users', 'auth/users', NULL, NULL, NULL),
(4, 2, 4, 'Roles', 'fa-user', 'auth/roles', NULL, NULL, NULL),
(5, 2, 5, 'Permission', 'fa-ban', 'auth/permissions', NULL, NULL, NULL),
(6, 2, 6, 'Menu', 'fa-bars', 'auth/menu', NULL, NULL, NULL),
(7, 2, 7, 'Operation log', 'fa-history', 'auth/logs', NULL, NULL, NULL),
(8, 0, 0, 'Food Category', 'fa-certificate', '/food-types', '*', '2021-11-08 04:58:13', '2022-01-01 00:16:59'),
(10, 0, 0, 'Users', 'fa-bars', '/users', '*', '2021-11-08 05:38:59', '2021-11-08 05:38:59'),
(11, 0, 0, 'Food', 'fa-beer', '/foods', '*', '2021-11-17 01:37:06', '2022-01-01 00:06:15'),
(12, 0, 0, 'Orders', 'fa-first-order', '/orders', '*', '2022-02-09 18:27:25', '2022-02-09 18:27:25'),
(13, 0, 0, 'Payment Setting', 'fa-dollar', '/business-settings', '*', '2022-02-27 22:24:23', '2022-02-27 22:24:23');
```

Comment: And which is line 1523? Not sure its actually related to this table

Comment: your table has no unique constraint so far, so wouldn't give that error, while inseting , but you can look into the sql file and check line 1523 maybe you really have an id twice

Comment: And what's your question about this? What have you tried to resolve your problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: If you are dumping data, why don't you simply remove the id field from the dump query?

Answer (score 0):

It seems likely to me that your `admin_menu` table already exists, so your `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` statement doesn't do anything.

And it seems likely that the existing table has this definition for the first column. It's not the same as the definition in your CREATE TABLE.

```sql
`id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
```

And it seems likely that the existing table already has a row with `id` = 1. So the first line of the INSERT you showed us fails on that duplicate key. Hence your error.

You seem to be doing some kind of dump/restore operation that's failing. It's hard to give you specific advice on this without knowing more about the workflow you are following.